# GCP Extensible Service Proxy encounters error when forwarding request

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, microservices

I have a the following setup:

```
1. Application (Java microservice) deployed on app engine.
2. Custom domain mapped to hit this service:.
   myfavmicroservice.project-amazing.dev.corporation.com
3. This endpoint is secured to require authentication by enabling IAP.

4. Configured ESP to intercept, authenticate and fulfill request to all 
   backend microservices (like above) with a common gateway endpoint.
5. Microservice is deployed using app.yaml.
6. ESP endpoint is configured using api.yaml (OpenAPI API Surface document)
```

This is the tutorial I am following:

```
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard
```

app.yaml to deploy the microservice:

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: java -jar tar/worker.jar
instance_class: F2 

service: myfavmicroservice

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

The ESP api.yaml for describing microservice api surface is like this

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: "My fav micro Service"
  description: "Serve my favorite microservice content"
  version: "1.0.0"

# This field will be replaced by the deploy_api.sh script.
host: microservice-system-gateway-5c4s43dedq-ue.a.run.app
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json

paths:
   /myfavmicroservice:
    get:
      summary: Greet the user
      operationId: hello
      description: "Get helloworld mainpage"
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://myfavmicroservice.project amazing.dev.corporation.com
       jwt_audience: .....
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "Success."
          schema:
            type: string
        '400':
          description: "The IATA code is invalid or missing."
          schema:
            type: string
```

But the problem is that whenever I make request to endpoint like this:

```
GET 
https://microservice-system-gateway-5c4s43dedq-ue.a.run.app/myfavmicroservice
```

I always get gateway 500 error. Upon inspection of ESP logs I am finding primarily

```
1. SSL Handshake Error with Error no 40
2. upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream
3. request: "GET /metadatasvc-hello HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[3461:f4f0:5678:a13::63]:443/myfavmicroservice
```

So the ESP is intercepting my request correctly, perhaps forwarding the request in correct format as well as evidenced from #3. But I am getting SSL error.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out the issue. For the benefit of stackoverflow community I am posting the solution here.

I figured that if you use custom domains that you map to app engine like this in the OpenAPI Configuration (That you deploy to ESP), SSL handshake fails:

```
 x-google-backend:
        address: https://my-microservice.my-custom-domain.company.com
```

However if you use the default URL that is assigned by APP Engine upon startup of the microservice like this, everything is fine:

```
x-google-backend:
        address: https://my-microservice.appspot.com
```

So I am trying to figure out how to use custom domain mappings in ESP OpenAPI configuration. For now though, if I do that the SSL proxying is not working inside ESP.